# Location of User Profiles in AEM 6.2 JCR?

Tags: aem

The out-of-the-box sample users that come with AEM are organized neatly in folders like `/home/users/geometrixx/` and user-names that correspond to their email addresses.

Why then when I create a user, does the profile get placed into a cryptic location like `/home/users/n/nspbWko6RBR1JWylKRiT/profile`, and how can I organize my own users into folders?

This particular implementation is not integrated with an identity provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the way Jackrabbit Oak works when dealing with [Authorizable node names](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/security/user/authorizablenodename.html) by default.

From the [official Adobe documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-3/administer/security/security-checklist.html):

> Since AEM 6.1, the way user (also known as authorizable) ID node names are stored is changed with a new implementation of the AuthorizableNodeName interface. The new interface will no longer expose the user ID in the node name, but will generate a random name instead.
>
> No configuration needs to be performed in order to enable it, as this is now the default way of generating authorizable IDs in AEM.
>
> Although not recommended, you can disable it in case you need the old implementation for backwards compatibility with your exsiting applications. In order to do this, you need to delete the Apache Jackrabbit Oak Random Authorizable Node Name OSGi configuration from the Web Console.

It shouldn't impact how you organize your users because you can always specify a directory to place your users in at the time of creation.

Comment: _you can always specify a directory to place your users in at the time of creation_ - how? I don't see this option.

Comment: you can specify a "home" for users/groups when creating them.

Comment: @AlexR when using /useradmin, you can specify the "path" property. when using /crx/explorer/index.jsp, you can specify the "Intermediate Path" property.

Comment: Thank you. The underlying problem here is that I was originally using `/libs/granite/security/content/userEditor.html` to manage users. I see a Path option when going through `/useradmin` instead.